# iOS 11 new viewport makes DisallowOverscroll not work?

Tags: ios, cordova, viewport, ios11

cordova -v : 7.0.1

Situation: I am porting cordova written (pure JS) app from iOS 8/9 (its not specified which version was written for) to iOS 11.

And I am encountering this problem with scrolling on the "main view".

What happens, as you know, iOS 11 has a new viewport ( https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/ ). 
So I am using that ( viewport-fit = cover) and everything goes in place as it been from the previous version.

However  if I touch the bottom of the "main view" i press and I do a motion for it to scroll, it does even though "the bottom of it" is fixed with bottom: 0px;

Ideas how can i fixed that?

DisallowOverscroll  is set to true.

I am using cordova-ios@4.4.0

It looks like this: 
[image: the bottom part comes only after a scroll event (Scroll should not be possible)]